# How to remove an xml node with two different names

Tags: vb.net, xmlnode

I tried to remove xml nodes that has 2 different Names with a function. Sometimes the word 
is used and other times a code - for example "year" and "b074"
I got an error saying Maximum number of errors has been exceeded.

```
 <Person>                            <Person>
    <Name> John </Name>                 <Name> John </Name>
    <age> 24 </age>                     <age> 24 </age>
    <DOB>                               <DOB>
      <year> 1990 </year>                  <b074> 1990 </b074>
      <month> 03 </month>                  <b678> 03 </b678>
      <date> 23 </date>                    <b745> 23 </b745>
    </DOB>                              </DOB>
 </Person>                           </Person>   

 Dim ShortName as Boolean 

 Function HandleTagName(name as string) as XName 
     Select Case name
         Case "Year", "b074"
            If ShortName Then
                Return "b074"
            Else
                Return "Year"

            End If
      End Select
 End Function 

Sub CompressFile()
   Dim Doc as XDocument

   If doc.<Person>.<DOB>.HandleTagName(<Year>) isNot Nothing Then
     doc.<Person>.<DOB>.HandleTagName(<Year>).Remove()
     count += count + 1
   End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: which errors are you getting?

Comment: BC30041: Maximum number of errors has been exceeded. - These are the only errors! Without the Function it works fine!

Comment: it should be providing more useful errors before that one brings it to a halt. check your output/debug windows.

Comment: I cant debug from a visual studio ... its done online - so when the page is selected thats when I'm able to view the errors. But as far as I can see everything else works! - If I remove the function, I don't have any errors.

Comment: is your function HandleTagName or HandleTag? It appears you are using both.

Comment: sorry typing error, HandleTagName

Comment: Also `count += count + 1` should be `count += 1` if its just increasing by 1

Comment: Thats true! - my counting is way off - made the changes ty... But still getting the error. BC30041: Maximum number of errors has been exceeded.